# Executing programs the efficient way with Spacemacs

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil, major-mode, scheme

I'm a Vim user trying to learn Spacemacs. In Vim, I execute a Scheme program by typing `:mit-scheme < xxx.scm`. After the program exits, I can continue editing simply by press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

However, doing this in Spacemacs (in evil mode, of course) would create a new buffer, which I have to kill manually by typing three characters: `<space> b d`. This is quite inconvenient for me, because I'm a inexperienced programmer who needs to execute programs *very* frequently while debugging.

[image]

How to make execute a program more efficiently in Spacemacs? For example, I want close the output window/buffer in one keystroke. I'm also glad to know if I can replace `:mit-scheme < xxx.scm` with some key bindings.

Comment: For scheme I think you could use something like Geiser http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/ which should help you do things much easier.

Comment: @caisah Seem that Geiser is shipped with the [Scheme layer](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/scheme/README.html). However, when I try to use those key bindings, a `SPC m is undefined` error is thrown.

Comment: @caisah I've installed the Scheme layer successfully! However, it only prints out the value of the last expression, while I want to see the value of *every* expression in a `.scm` file, just like what happens when I feed the whole file to a REPL.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an workaround: open an terminal in Emacs with the [Shell layer](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+tools/shell/README.html). After installing the Shell layer, you can toggle a shell window using `SPC '​`.

You can execute `mit-scheme < xxx.scm` in that terminal, which seems more convenient to me than using the [Scheme layer](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/scheme/README.html)

[image]